# jquery malipulate a subarray, and return a new array using each/map

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, loops

I have this string in the form of

`ItemName1:Rate1:Tax1_ItemName2:Rate2:Tax2:_ItemName3:Rate3:Tax3_ItemName4:Rate4:Tax4` (and so on, upto item 25).

What I have to do is, user will pass a index, (say 2) grab the item at that index, when this string is split by `_`, for eg. if index is 2, I would get the substring `ItemName3:Rate3:Tax3`. another thing the user will pass is 3 args, indicating `newItem`, `newRate`, and `newTax`, then I have to replace these old items found at that particular index with these new values **and** return the new string. Perhaps an example would make it clear

```
var itemList=ItemName1:Rate1:Tax1_ItemName2:Rate2:Tax2:_ItemName3:Rate3:Tax3_ItemName4:Rate4:Tax4
```

user passed arguments, `2, Denim Jeans, 399.00, 14.34`.
This must replace the original `itemList` and return

```
ItemName1:Rate1:Tax1_ItemName2:Rate2:Tax2:_Denim Jeans:399.00:14.34_ItemName4:Rate4:Tax4
```

(Hope I made myself clear).
I know the simplest way would be first split the `itemList` by `_` and then at given index, split by `:` and then replace those items, then using a for loop make a new string and then return that new string. But it seems like a lot of work. Isn't there a simple way that this could be achieved by using `.each()` and/or `.map()`, though may be inside a `for`, I won't mind that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var items = str.split('_').map(function(v){ return v.split(':') });
```

That will generate an array:

```
[
  ["ItemName1","Rate1","Tax1"],
  ["ItemName2","Rate2","Tax2"],
  ["ItemName3","Rate3","Tax3"],
  ["ItemName4","Rate4","Tax4"]
]
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/7uVDM/