# jQuery replace string at a particular index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

Okay, this is quite related to my [previous quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434122/jquery-malipulate-a-subarray-and-return-a-new-array-using-each-map), but still (so you don't have to travel to that page..)

I have a string in the format

```
ItemName1:Rate1:Tax1_ItemName2:Rate2:Tax2:_ItemName3:Rate3:Tax3_ItemName4:Rate4:Tax4
```

the user will pass 4 args, first will tell which element to take, when this list is split by `_`, and other 3 will tell the new values of items.
For example, if user passes `2, Denim Jeans, 399.00, 14.34`. The original string would become

```
ItemName1:Rate1:Tax1_ItemName2:Rate2:Tax2:_Denim Jeans:399.00:14.34_ItemName4:Rate4:Tax4
```

First split at `_`, get the element at index `2` (the value user supplied), and then split that element at `:` and then replace those items with the value supplied.

I got around a lot, here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k87Zw/3/) for that. But I am just stuck at the last part that will do the appropriate concatenation.
Can help please help me make this last function?

*Edit* : updated the fiddle!

Comment: What's the purpose of the first `$.map()` call in your function?

Comment: With the answer I posted in the other question you get a proper array of items from a string with that format, if you want to change something in that array you can do it by index. I don't quite get what' you're trying to do though. Can't you just use an object instead?

Comment: @nnnnnn:
after the `list` is split by `_`, map returns the elements of that element when split by `:`, which is then concatenated to make the string that will be replace.

Comment: @elclanrs:
I tried using an object, but couldn't event get to this part of forming string that will be replaced. If you want, I can post a detailed explanation of the scenario and what I am exactly trying to do.

Comment: Wouldn't `_itemsToReplace = ary[index].split(deli2);` do the same thing as that first `$.map()`? (If the callback you pass to `$.map()` just returns the first parameter unchanged all you're doing is making a shallow copy of the array.)

Comment: @nnnnnn:
bulls***! Never thought of that! thanks I'll update the fiddle and the link, but what about the last part? The last function that will do the required replacement?

Comment: @nnnnnn:
updated the fiddle and link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of things here...

Not sure why you are taking list as a string. it would have been better you have used a json object.

and in your example you are getting the 2nd string in the required format..so it doesn't make sense to split it and join again.. you just need to replace the array item with the argList

here is the modified jsfidle. hope i understood your problem right. tell me if there are any gaps...
http://jsfiddle.net/k87Zw/5/

Comment: Thanks man! that did the trick! +1 and thanks for making it clear, I was really confused!